# How can I get my background showing in javascript css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im trying to use a background image within iScroll's javascript. The script seems to use css within the javascript and does allow me to add a background colour but not an image for some reason. Is there a way around this so that I can use an image?

here is the section of the code that im trying to get to show the background image (images/scrollbar_bg.png)

```
if (that.options.scrollbarClass) 
bar.className = that.options.scrollbarClass + dir.toUpperCase();

else bar.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;z-index:100; 
absolute; left: 0px; margin-left: 14px; background-url: images/scrollbar_bg.png; '

 + (dir == 'h' ? 'height:7px; bottom:20px; left:2px; right:
' + (that.vScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px' : 'width:7px;bottom:' 
+ (that.hScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 
'px;top:14px;right:1px -border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get `background-url` from? The correct syntax would be this:

```
background-image: url(images/scrollbar_bg.png);
```

Also, you have a random `absolute;` sitting in the middle of your `z-index` and `left` properties.

Comment: Thanks animuson however that code seems to give me an error in dreamweaver and doesn't work :(

Comment: I just seem to get a red line on that row when I use your syntax

see for yourself <BR />

if (that.options.scrollbarClass) bar.className = that.options.scrollbarClass + dir.toUpperCase();
   else bar.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;z-index:100; left: 0px; margin-left: 14px; background-image: url(images/scrollbar_bg.png);
 ' + (dir == 'h' ? 'height:7px; bottom:20px; left:2px; right:' + (that.vScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px' : 'width:7px;bottom:' + (that.hScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px;top:14px;right:1px -border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px');

Comment: @Dan: Have you tried testing it in your browser? Dreamweaver is not giving me any syntax errors for that code. Try making sure it's all on one line.

Comment: Ah thanks man, yeah I think it was because I needed to place line breaks in to post the code on here which it didnt seem to like back the source code

Thanks alot!